# Vector projection/rejection in C#?

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a function for [vector rejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) in C#. That is:

[image]

I have been trying to code this formula in C# however for some reason it's always returning zero. This is what I have until now:

```
private Vector3 Projection(Vector3 vectorA, Vector3 vectorB) {
    Vector3 a2 = Vector3.Scale ( Divide (Vector3.Scale (vectorA, vectorB), Vector3.Scale (vectorB, vectorB)), vectorB);
    return a2;
}

private Vector3 Rejection(Vector3 vectorA, Vector3 vectorB) {
    Vector3 a2 = vectorA - Projection(vectorA, vectorB);
    return a2;
}

private Vector3 Divide(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    Vector3 c = new Vector3 ();
    c.x = a.x / b.x;
    c.y = a.y / b.y;
    c.z = a.z / b.z;
    return c;
}

private void Example() {
    Vector3 a = new Vector3 (5, 5, 0);
    Vector3 b = new Vector3 (0, 10, 0);
    Vector3 c = Rejection(a, b); // Returns (NaN, 0, NaN)
}

// The Vector3 class represents a 3D vector and it's x, y and z components are of float type. It's [scale method][3] multiplies two vectors component wise.
```

Example:

Imagine Vector A is a force applied to an object that moves along the ground and Vector B is the gravity (which is perpendicular to the ground). When Vector A is applied to the object the trajectory it moves should be a third vector perpendicular to the gravity, which can be thought of as A travelling perpendicular to B. That's is the rejection of A from B.

[image]

Comment: can you post the definition of `Vector` (especially the types of x,y,z) and the definition of `Scale`? Also, what parameters are you feeding in? What is it returning? You say it returns zero, but it returns a vector so that is impossible.

Comment: You might want to tag this question as specific to Unity since you're asking about the functionality of Unity's `Vector3` class.

Comment: Hi I didn't realize the class was specific to Unity. I can use a different one but I'll tag it to Unity.

Comment: So can you give an example of the sort of inputs you're putting into it and what the expected and actual outputs are?

Comment: I don't think you can have a vector that is both perpendicular to B and also points in the same direction as A, since A is not itself perpendicular to B. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, please give some numbers though so people can try and trace through the code and identify the error. What are some actual vectors you're passing to the function, what output do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: I just added the actual output I'm getting when feeding it two vectors. And also an example of a real world problem.

Comment: Is `Vector3.Scale (vectorA, vectorB)` the inner product, and equal to `Ax*Bx+Ay*By+Az*Bz` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation `a·b` represents the [vector dot product](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html) and the result is a scalar value.

So you need is code like this:

```
public struct Vector3
{
    public readonly double x, y, z;
    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
    public double Dot(Vector3 other)
    {
        return x*other.x+y*other.y+z*other.z;
    }
    public Vector3 Scale(double factor)
    {
        return new Vector3(factor*x, factor*y, factor*z);
    }
    public Vector3 Add(Vector3 other)
    {
        return new Vector3(x+other.x, y+other.y, z+other.z);
    }
    public static Vector3 operator+(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) { return a.Add(b); }
    public static Vector3 operator-(Vector3 a) { return a.Scale(-1); }
    public static Vector3 operator-(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) { return a.Add(-b); }
    public static Vector3 operator*(double f, Vector3 a) { return a.Scale(f); }
    public static Vector3 operator/(Vector3 a, double d) { return a.Scale(1/d); }
    public static double operator*(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) { return a.Dot(b); }

    public Vector3 Projection(Vector3 other)
    {
        // (scalar/scalar)*(vector) = (vector)
        return (other*this)/(other*other)*other;
    }
    public Vector3 Rejection(Vector3 other)
    {
        // (vector)-(vector) = (vector)
        return this-Projection(other);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A=new Vector3(5, 5, 0);
        var B=new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
        var C=A.Rejection(B);
        // C = { 5,0,0}, expected answer from math {5,5,0}-0.5*{0,10,0}
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can move the code outside the `Vector3` class if you have no control over it

```
// Vector3 defined elsewhere with .x, .y and .z fields

class VectorAlgebra
{
    public static Vector3 Subtract(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        return new Vector3(a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y, a.z-b.z);
    }
    public static Vector3 Scale(float f, Vector3 a)
    {
        return new Vector3(f*a.x, f*a.y, f*a.z);
    }

    public static float Dot(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        return (a.x*b.x)+(a.y*b.y)+(a.z*b.z);
    }

    public static Vector3 Projection(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        return Scale(Dot(a, b)/Dot(b, b), b);
    }
    public static Vector3 Rejection(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        return Subtract(a, Projection(a, b));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A=new Vector3(5, 5, 0);
        var B=new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
        var C=Rejection(A, B);
        // C = { 5,0,0}, expected answer from math {5,5,0}-0.5*{0,10,0}
    }
}
```

See when you code the rules of vector algebra the coding for Projection and Rejection become identical to the formulation in the math books. You can check the answer with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B5%2C5%2C0%5D-%28%5B5%2C5%2C0%5D.%5B0%2C10%2C0%5D%29%2F%28%5B0%2C10%2C0%5D.%5B0%2C10%2C0%5D%29*%5B0%2C10%2C0%5D).

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html), seems like `Scale` **is** the dot product, though I agree it's odd terminology.

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver. Also I was moving the code outside Vector3 and you saved me a lot of work. I'll edit the answer with what I used in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that we have some numbers let's break down the steps

```
Vector3.Scale ( Divide (Vector3.Scale (vectorA, vectorB), Vector3.Scale (vectorB, vectorB)), vectorB);
```

is

```
var numerator = Vector3.Scale (vectorA, vectorB);
var denominator = Vector3.Scale (vectorB, vectorB);
var divided = Divide(numerator, denominator);
var result = Vector3.Scale(divided, vectorB);
```

which working through your numbers would be

```
vectorA = (5,5,0)
vectorB = (0,10,0)
numerator = (0,50,0)
denominator = (0,100,0)
divided = (NaN,.5,NaN) <- since you can't divide by zero
result = (NaN,5,NaN)
```

Not sure why you're getting a 0 for the second dimension instead of a 5 (a typo? some sort of type casting issue?) but hopefully this explains why you have `NaN`s popping up.

Comment: The trick is that `Scale()` returns a scalar, and there is no need for vector division with `Divide()`.

Comment: @ja72 That's not what the documentation for `Scale` shows - in the docs it returns a vector

Comment: In the other comment you mentioned `Scale` is the dot product. It cannot be a dot product and return a vector.

Comment: Oh you're right, its not a dot product sorry, it just does multiplies each component